# Error No 1. On button click event when i use debug it shows yellow line on the first line and then it is skipped i don't know how but it is skipped

Tags: c#, asp.net

First line it is showing yellow line and then it is skipped to return i don't know how? Does it means it is not showing taking values?

```
private void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cmbxschl.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        lblmsg.Text = "Please Select School Name";
        lblmsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        lblmsg.Visible = true;
        cmbxschl.Focus();
        return;
    }
    if (txtcls.Text.Trim().ToString() == "")
    {
        lblmsg.Text = "Please Enter Class Name";
        lblmsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        lblmsg.Visible = true;
        txtcls.Focus();
        return;
    }
    save();
}
```

After then it returns to another cs file

```
public static int ExecuteNonQuery(SqlConnection connection, CommandType commandType, string commandText, params SqlParameter[] commandParameters)        
{

    if (connection == null) 
         throw new ArgumentNullException("connection");

     // Create a command and prepare it for execution
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
     bool mustCloseConnection = false;
     PrepareCommand(cmd, connection, (SqlTransaction)null, commandType, commandText, commandParameters, out mustCloseConnection);

     // Finally, execute the command
     int retval = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //Showing error in this line saying that error converting nvarchar to int

     // Detach the SqlParameters from the command object, so they can be used again
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
     if (mustCloseConnection)
            connection.Close();
     return retval;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If a line is skipped over, that means it was not executed. It's most likely that the debugger was showing you it was evaluating an `IF` statement, and because it evaluated to `false`, it skipped the `IF (true) ...` part and continued on.